# post multipart/form-data with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, jqbootstrapvalidation

I want to post my form by ajax, the form contains some text fields and one file field, I used bootstrapValidator to validate the form, here is my code:

ajax:

```
$('#profile').bootstrapValidator({

        // some validations here

    }).on('success.form.bv', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(e.target),                        // The form instance
        bv  = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');   // BootstrapValidator instance

        var formData = new FormData($form);

        $.post('index.php', formData, function(response) {
...
```

but the post request didn't sent, so where is the error in my code?

Comment: If post request sent, you can see how is you formData inside request payload in dev tools. How does it look?

Comment: Did you tried var `formData = new FormData($form[0]);` ?

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers i din't get your question, also i don't have previous experience with FormData

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers yes I tried that

Comment: in Chrome dev tools, AJAX requests can be showed in the `network` tab. I think all browsers have such tool. each request contains information about request headers, response headers and data send (for instance formData) and data received. I have no experince with formData I used them only one time in my life for file upload and I remember that I was able to see data appended to formData in `Request payload`.

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers the request didn't sent in all cases, if it is sent so I don't have any problems to discuss here

Comment: So I misunderstood question  when you said `but the post request sent, so where is the error in my code?`  I am sorry.

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers I am sorry, I mean didn't sent